# SQL Sequence column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add new column to my SQL Query so i can sort the results afterwards by some ID (integer) and not by name (string).

The problem is I want to make sure that some of the names to be with highest SequenceID so i can put them at the end.
I came up with something like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IIF([Name] = N'something', 'zzzzSomething', [Name]) ASC) AS SequenceID
```

Any better implementation?

Comment: Your snippet only takes into account one name. Do you need more than one?

Comment: Why not to sort by string? Anyway if there is some specific reason for that (I can't imagine witch one) the only suggestion I can give is to use CASE statement instead of IIF as with IIF your indexes will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort first by special name or not and then by name:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                    case name when N'John' then 3 when N'Mary' then 2 else 1 end, name
                  ) AS SequenceID
```

This sorts `'John'` last, and before that `'Mary'`, and before that all other names in alphabetic order.